# Is $\int_{\infty}^{\infty^2} f(t) dt$ always $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f(t)$ be Riemann-integrable and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) dt=1$.

If I now look at the limit $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{F(x)}$, where

$$F(x)=\int_{x}^{x^2} f(t) dt$$

I wonder if this limit always has to be $0$ or if it is possible that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{F(x)} \neq 0$ ?

---

In my opinion this is not possible, since $f(t)$ has to be bounded by definition, thus it has to converge for $x \rightarrow \pm\infty$.

However I'd like to know if the fact, that my Integral goes from $\infty$ to "$\infty^2$" could make some trouble.

Comment: How do you define $\infty^2$?

Comment: This is exactly the point and I sadly can't really make up a clean definition for myself, that wouldn't cause logical flaws.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it has to be $0$. Let $G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}G(x)=1$. But$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{x^2}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\lim_{x\to\infty}G(x^2)-G(x)=1-1=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I generalise, that for Integrals like that $\infty = \infty^2$?

Comment: I cannot answer that question because I do not undertand what is it that you mean by that, Note that my answer made no use of the expression $\infty^2$.

Comment: Yes. Really good way of avoiding it. I just caught my flaw at thinking about infinity. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

If $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \,dt=1$ then by definition there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\int_{x}^{c} f(t) \,dt + \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{c}^{x} f(t) \,dt= \int_{-\infty}^{c} f(t) \,dt + \int_{c}^{\infty} f(t) \,dt =1$$

In particular these two limits exist.

Now we have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{x}^{x^2} f(t) \,dt = \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{c}^{x^2} f(t) \,dt - \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{c}^{x} f(t) \,dt =  \int_{c}^{\infty} f(t) \,dt - \int_{c}^{\infty} f(t) \,dt =0$$

Comment: At the first line did you miss the square of the upper integral limit? $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\int_{x}^{c} f(t) \,dt + \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{c}^{x^2} f(t) \,dt$

Comment: @MLK No, I just used the definition of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,dt = 1$. But yes, you can write it like that because $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{c}^{x^2} f(t) \,dt = \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{c}^{x} f(t) \,dt$$

Comment: Ah I see that's neat. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

$$F(x)=\int_{x}^{x^2} f(t) dt = \int_{0}^{x^2} f(t) dt -\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$$

Both the integrals on the RHS converge to  $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) dt$ as $x\to \infty$